# Angular nested subscribe conditional, based on dialog confirmation

Tags: angular, rest

I am using following versions:
Angular CLI: 10.0.6
Node: 12.18.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.0.10

I have the following requirement. Basically, I have 3 levels or calls.

- 1st Service call to check if duplicate data exits or not. It will return empty array if not existing.
- 2nd to check If the above service returns the data, I will pop up a dialog, warning user that data is duplicated. User can cancel -> no action. Else user can confirm -> based on this, 3rd call where I need to call another service; which will have its own simple subscription and error handling.
- If no duplicate found (based on 2nd call), then proceed to save.

So my last service call should be dependent on 'Confirm' of dialog OR no duplicate found?

I am trying something like below, but unable to get it.

```
// Other code
this.myService.loadDuplicateData(requestPayload) // First call
          .pipe(
            switchMap(
              data => {
                this.existingData = data;
                if (this.existingData.dbData.length > 0) { // If data exists, ask for confirmation. Do nothing if Cancel, else proceed with 3rd call.
                  // Means data is already available.
                  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AlertDialogComponent);
                  // Here I will call afterClosed which has subscribe and pipe option
                  // what should I return here, so it can be subscribe to the above "pipe"
                  
                }
              }
            )
          ).subscribe { // subscribe for the pipe
             // Ideally 3rd service call will be called if no duplicate OR confirm to save irrespective of duplicate. Should not be called if "Cancel" dialog.
          }
```

------------ **UPDATE** ---------

I tried the below:

```
this.myService.getExistingData(requestPayload)
          .pipe(
            switchMap(
              data => {
                if(data.existingData.length > 0) {
                  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AlertDialogComponent);
                  return dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
                    map(
                      res => {
                        if (res == 'confirm') {
                          return of(data);
                        } else {
                          return never();
                        }
                      }
                    ),
                  );
                } 
              }
            ),
            switchMap(
              data => {
                console.log("Second switchmap: " + data);
                
                return this.myService.loadUploads(requestPayload);
              }
            )
          ).subscribe(
            data => {
              this.resetRows();
              this.isSuccess = true;
            },
            error =>  {
              //check error
            }
          );
```

- Now, the dialog pops up if duplicate data found. However, if clicked on Cancel or Confirm (both) proceeds to save the data. How should I not proceed if clicked cancel?
- If no duplicate found, it throws error "ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.". This is because I do not have "else" if no duplicate found. How to handle that i.e what to return if i need to save records if no duplicate?

"loadUploads" method is saving rows.